# How can I get a total of all asks and bids from Binance using this curl on Linux?

Tags: linux, curl, bitcoin

This curl input will output a nice list of bids and asks from Binance's API:

```
curl https://api.binance.com/api/v1/depth?symbol=ETHUSDT | jq
```

But is there a way to calculate the total of all those asks and bids so that output is something like:

```
Total asks: 1023411 USD
Total bids: 1002112 USD
```

Answer (score 1):

While not the shortest version, this jq script does the job:

```
{asks, bids} | to_entries
| .[]
| . as {key: $kind, value: $data}
| $data
| map({price: .[0] | tonumber, qty: .[1] | tonumber})
| map(.price * .qty)
| add
| "Total \($kind): \(. * 100 | round / 100) USD"
```

Run as `jq -r -f filename.jq` or `jq -r '{asks, bids} | .....'`

Note that jq is limited to the precision of a IEEE 754 'double'.

(Also it seems that the API only returns a maximum of 100 items by default (up to 1000), so this might not be the correct numbers anyway. [See docs.](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#market-data-endpoints))